# Restrict users from particular Gmail domain to login using OAuth2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

How to restrict the user login to a particular domain before it logs in to the gmail. I am creating an chrome extension to which should permit only to the domain. I have used oauth2 to get the token but this after user had logged in. I have added "hd" : "domain.com" in manifest.json under oauth in my chrome extension but it is getting token from all gmail users.

Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "BT_auth",
"short_name": "BT_auth",
"description": "",
"version": "0.0.1",
"minimum_chrome_version": "38",

"icons": {
  "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
  "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
},

"app": {
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
},
"permissions" : [
  "identity"
  ],

"oauth2" : {
"client_id" : "**********",
"scopes" : [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
  ],
"access_type" : "online",
    "hd" : "browntape.com"
},

 "key" : "***********"
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id = "button" 
   style = "padding : 8px;
   background-color: yellow;
   display: inline-block;">
   Gmail Access!!
 </div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive" : true}, function(token){
        console.log(token);
    })
  })
};
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html',{
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600}
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: show all relevant code. Cant see how you will achieve this just with a manifest. Are you aware what is that oauth section for?

Comment: I am using oauth to get the gmail token of the logged in gmail user of browntape domain. Ex. marc@browntape.com

Comment: Where did you find any documentation that would indicate `oauth2.access_type` or `oauth2.hd` as expected manifest keys?

Comment: It is not specified in manifest.json docs but it is specified oauth2, I want to restrict my extension only to a domain, so tried `hd` in manifest.json but it is not working.

Comment: please can anyone suggest me any other method...if not possible by this one.